# HTML Radiobuton values in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, radio-button

I'm having some real problems with a group of HTML Radiobuttons when I try to pass the selected values back and forth between JavaScript and ASP.NET.

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="markerSel" value="1" checked=true />
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="markerSel" value="2" />
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="markerSel" value="3" />
```

To begin with, the form loads with these radiobuttons and a user selects a value and submits the ASP.NET form. To get the value of the selected option on the server-side I have tried;

```
string selVal = Request.Form["markerSel"]; 
//always returns "1", regardless of the selection made.
```

And also tried ASP.NET's FindControl method (recursively too), and I just get null.

I want to be able to set the value of this radiobutton group via JavaScript and Asp.NET and be able to read from both environments.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't use ASP.NET radio buttons instead of `<input type=radio />`?

If you use

```
<asp:RadioButton id="radio1" runat="server" Checked="true" />
<asp:RadioButton id="radio2" runat="server" />
<asp:RadioButton id="radio3" runat="server" />
```

You will be able to access them server-side by doing `this.radio1.Checked`

If you want to access your elements via javascript, you can do a `document.getElementById('radio1')` and you will get the DOM element that way.

If you want to use jQuery, you can access the radio buttons with

```
$('#radio1')
```

If you want to test if the radio button is checked, you can use

```
if ($("#radio1").is(':checked')) {//...
```

Comment: Thanks Hugo, I've tried to use asp:RadioButton. But for some reason JQuery UI didn't work well with that. It never looked right, but I have now sorted it using <%= checkedVal%> syntax within the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm... I would try changing the line to:

```
string selVal = Request.Form("markerSel");
```